# How to order an array of ranges by position

Tags: javascript, range, comments

I get a range with this, in div with `contenteditable` mode :

```
var sel = document.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
//...
comments.push(range);
```

The text in div only has html tags `<br>` and `<mark>` (highlighted comments). As range.startOffset and range.endOffset concern the container (and not the div with contenteditable mode), I don't know how to order ranges according to their position in the text (from top to bottom).

Help me, please.

Comment: could you add some examples?

Comment: Can the ranges overlap?

Comment: @Oriol : no, but comment in comment is possible.

Comment: @NinaScholz: The goal is to create a system of comments (like in LibreOffice Writer). The array `comments` will be used to draw (or redraw) highlighting and annotations in the margin. The sort will manage the placement of annotations in height (in the margin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort your ranges by starting positions, you can use

```
comments.sort(r1, r2) {
  var comp = r1.startContainer.compareDocumentPosition(r2.startContainer);
  if(comp & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING) return -1;
  if(comp & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING) return +1;
  return r1.startOffset - r2.startOffset;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's perfect ! Just use "sort" with this way : `comments.sort(function(r1, r2) {...});`